# DFA memory bandwidth

Tags: automata, finite-automata, memory-access

When we talk about DFA, we say that each new character from the input requires one memory access. What does that mean?

This is what I think about this. Please tell me is this right? 
For example, I have a transition table stored for a certain regular expression in memory (RAM). Now, for each input character the CPU will fetch the whole transition table to find out the next state. In this way, we have just one memory access?

Comment: DFA are their own model in which there is no such thing as "memory". So I take it you are talking about an *implementation* of an algorithm that is derived from a DFA. In which machine model do you want to analyse memory accesses then?

Comment: @Raphael. Minor nit, but I take issue with your assertion that a DFA has no memory. It "remembers" its current state, and, as we know, that can be used to "remember" the sequence of the most recent $k$ inputs, for a fixed $k$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how memory access works. For each character read, you need (1) to read the character, (2) to access the transition table at the appropriate state and character. In your case it seems that we're not counting (1), and so (2) is the single memory access. The *speed* of this access depends on how big the transition table is. If it is small enough to fit in cache (which is usually the case), then after several transitions, the entire transition table would be in cache and so would be accessed quickly. If it is too big, you will have cache misses and everything would be slower. But in both cases only the particular cell is accessed! However, data is stored in caches in chunks knows as *cache lines*, which could explain your confusion (cache lines are not big enough to hold the entire transition table). Note also that there are several levels of cache.

Comment: So, when the transition table is large then we can't access the whole transition table in one memory access? Isn't it?

Comment: It's still one memory access, but it's more expensive since you're accessing the main memory rather than the cache.